How to make more efficient sequential analysis in R
I want to implement a battery system for a renewable plant of energy who feeds a machine. For example, The machine requires 1000 kw/h or the energy closest to that amount. If the energy generated exceeds 1000 kw/h, the surplus could be used to charge the battery, which, let's say, is 100 kw. If the energy produced is less than 1000 kw/h and there is energy in the battery, the energy from the battery should be used to power the machine. An example generated energy dataset could be the following:
data set energia



Path
Hour 1
Hour 2
Hour 3
Hour 4
Hour 5
Hour 6
...
Hour 8760




1
950,0
947,1
982,4
1013,5
1003,0
1087,7
...



2
1046,9
947,9
981,9
1031,9
984,8
931,8
...



3
996,1
1031,0
978,8
972,7
826,8
952,0
...



4
943,4
1015,2
1007,2
994,8
1017,4
979,8
...




Where should I obtain a new energy and battery charge level data set as follows:
data set Bateria



Path
Hour 1
Hour 2
Hour 3
Hour 4
Hour 5
Hour 6




1
0,0
0,0
0,0
13,5
16,5
100,0


2
46,9
0,0
0,0
31,9
16,7
0,0


3
0,0
31,0
9,8
0,0
0,0
0,0


4
0,0
15,2
22,3
17,2
34,6
14,4












New data set Energia



Path
Hour 1
Hour 2
Hour 3
Hour 4
Hour 5
Hour 6




1
950,0
947,1
982,4
1013,5
1003,0
1087,7


2
1046,9
994,8
981,9
1031,9
1000,0
948,5


3
996,1
1031,0
1000,0
982,5
826,8
952,0


4
943,4
1015,2
1007,2
1000,0
1017,4
1000,0



I am doing the simulation for-loop each of the hours in 1 year (8760) with a thousand possible paths of energy generation values. I am currently making a for for each column where I check the conditions (ther is more conditions), the code is the next:
carga_bateria<- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 1040, ncol = 8760))
for (i in 2:8760) {  
cond1<-energia[,i]>pot_elec
carga_bateria[cond1,i]=carga_bateria[cond1,i-1]*(1-0.02/100)+pmin(n_bat*7.55-carga_bateria[cond1,i-1]*(1-0.02/100),(energia[cond1,i]-pot_elec)*0.85)
# si la energia generada es mayor a la necsitada entonces la bateria queda con la carga anterior con la perdida de 0.02% + el minimo entre
#la bateria que hace falta y el excedente generado incluyendo la perdida de eficiencia al cargar de 85%.

cond2<-(energia[,i]+pmax(carga_bateria[,i-1]*(1-0.02/100)-n_bat*7.55*0.2,0))<pot_elec*0.3#cuando ni incluyendo la bateria en t-1 llega al 30% de la capacidad del electrolizador, entonces tambien se carga bateria
carga_bateria[cond2,i]=carga_bateria[cond2,i-1]*(1-0.02/100)+pmin(n_bat*7.55-carga_bateria[cond2,i-1]*(1-0.02/100),(energia[cond2,i])*0.85)

cond3<- pot_elec>energia[,i]&(pot_elec-energia[,i])<(carga_bateria[,i-1]*(1-0.02/100)-n_bat*7.55*0.2)#Caso desacarga parcial bateria, si el faltante lo puede cubrir la bateria
carga_bateria[cond3,i]=carga_bateria[cond3,i-1]*(1-0.02/100)-(pot_elec-energia[cond3,i]) #la bateria se descargaga en ese faltante
energia[cond3,i]<- pot_elec #la energia llega a la capacidad

cond4<- (energia[,i]+pmax(carga_bateria[,i-1]*(1-0.02/100)-n_bat*7.55*0.2,0))>pot_elec*0.3&(energia[,i]+pmax(carga_bateria[,i-1]*(1-0.02/100)-n_bat*7.55*0.2,0))<pot_elec# caso de descarga total
carga_bateria[cond4,i]= n_bat*7.55*0.2#la bateria se descargaga totalmente
energia[cond4,i]<- energia[cond4,i]+(carga_bateria[cond4,i-1]*(1-0.02/100)-n_bat*7.55*0.2) #la energia llega a la capacidad


cond99<-!cond1&!cond2&!cond3&!cond4
carga_bateria[cond99,i]=carga_bateria[cond99,i-1]*(1-0.02/100)
validacion[1,i]<-sum(cond1);validacion[2,i]<-sum(cond2);validacion[3,i]<-sum(cond3);validacion[4,i]<-sum(cond4)
validacion[5,i]<- sum(cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4)

}

but I want to make the process as efficient as possible. I would believe that parallelization is not an option since the analysis is sequential and conditional, although I don't know.

Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code for you, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it for yourself. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Hi! I added the code that i am currently using. The code works, i  just will like to make it more efficient. The real code evaluates more conditions That's why I hadn't included it. i dont want to someone make me the code, with a clue of what kind od tool i can use is enough for me . Thanks for your Help!!

Your code works and you want to optimize? That's a better fit for CodeReview. p.s. I have not read the question in details.

I will try it , thaks for the help.

Vectorizing what we can. Additional speed would probably have to come from Rcpp.
Example data:
energia <- matrix(rnorm(876e4, 1e3, 20), 1e3)

Process:
system.time({
  Bateria <- array(0, dim(energia))
  Energia <- energia - 1e3
  Bateria[,1] <- pmax(pmin(Energia[,1], 100), 0)
  for (i in 2:ncol(energia)) {
    Bateria[,i] <- pmax(pmin(Bateria[,i - 1] + Energia[,i], 100), 0)
  }
  Energia[,1] <- energia[,1]
  Energia[,-1] <- energia[,-1] - pmin(0, Rfast::coldiffs(Bateria))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.49    0.15    0.62

Resulting in
energia[1:10, 1:7]
#>            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
#>  [1,] 1020.3650  973.7161 1012.1916 1011.4977 1003.0202  999.4796 1036.0359
#>  [2,] 1029.7795  988.7669  994.9009  958.9296  995.9292  958.8030  983.2274
#>  [3,]  977.9996 1000.7481  995.8109  972.9857  990.2269 1000.8311  992.5563
#>  [4,] 1003.8806  998.7856  985.7410 1015.4744 1023.4497 1001.2701 1017.1896
#>  [5,] 1013.1368 1035.9297  998.8231  990.3747 1013.2639  983.5665 1000.1635
#>  [6,] 1011.3533 1021.4186 1012.0547  988.0986  982.9560 1045.1527  972.7560
#>  [7,]  994.0441  997.9712  996.2793  983.3372  954.3548  998.1092 1005.5494
#>  [8,]  970.3797 1005.9268 1033.7725 1008.7859 1015.1895 1037.7978  986.7629
#>  [9,]  966.4012  999.3218  998.5642  977.3220 1018.2797 1007.8780 1009.1757
#> [10,] 1038.1993 1002.0838 1002.3877 1001.0923  975.2968  930.2707 1002.9185
Bateria[1:10, 1:7]
#>           [,1]       [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]        [,6]      [,7]
#>  [1,] 20.36501  0.0000000 12.19160 23.68929 26.70945  26.1890759 62.225017
#>  [2,] 29.77954 18.5464758 13.44736  0.00000  0.00000   0.0000000  0.000000
#>  [3,]  0.00000  0.7481351  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000   0.8311082  0.000000
#>  [4,]  3.88059  2.6661657  0.00000 15.47445 38.92413  40.1942133 57.383772
#>  [5,] 13.13683 49.0665635 47.88970 38.26436 51.52831  35.0948033 35.258318
#>  [6,] 11.35329 32.7718892 44.82658 32.92519 15.88119  61.0338416 33.789819
#>  [7,]  0.00000  0.0000000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000   0.0000000  5.549418
#>  [8,]  0.00000  5.9267888 39.69932 48.48522 63.67473 100.0000000 86.762890
#>  [9,]  0.00000  0.0000000  0.00000  0.00000 18.27970  26.1576981 35.333428
#> [10,] 38.19931 40.2830995 42.67077 43.76306 19.05989   0.0000000  2.918507
Energia[1:10, 1:7]
#>            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
#>  [1,] 1020.3650  994.0811 1012.1916 1011.4977 1003.0202 1000.0000 1036.0359
#>  [2,] 1029.7795 1000.0000 1000.0000  972.3769  995.9292  958.8030  983.2274
#>  [3,]  977.9996 1000.7481  996.5590  972.9857  990.2269 1000.8311  993.3874
#>  [4,] 1003.8806 1000.0000  988.4071 1015.4744 1023.4497 1001.2701 1017.1896
#>  [5,] 1013.1368 1035.9297 1000.0000 1000.0000 1013.2639 1000.0000 1000.1635
#>  [6,] 1011.3533 1021.4186 1012.0547 1000.0000 1000.0000 1045.1527 1000.0000
#>  [7,]  994.0441  997.9712  996.2793  983.3372  954.3548  998.1092 1005.5494
#>  [8,]  970.3797 1005.9268 1033.7725 1008.7859 1015.1895 1037.7978 1000.0000
#>  [9,]  966.4012  999.3218  998.5642  977.3220 1018.2797 1007.8780 1009.1757
#> [10,] 1038.1993 1002.0838 1002.3877 1001.0923 1000.0000  949.3306 1002.9185

